# Button to change value in SQL without any redirection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to use Javascript to pass the value from a button
to execute a PHP Script (The script simply changed a boolean column to 1 / True.

However i cannot get the code to work, i am not sure if its my Formatting, but i am not very familiar with Javascript

i am simply trying to change the value in the SQL Database on a column without any redirection.

index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $("body").on("click","button", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting a form ...
        let data={id: $(this).data("id")}
        $.post("viewed.php",data)
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log("Message:",result);
            });
    });
</script>
```

My Button index.php

```
            <div><button name="Delete" data-id='<?echo $data['orderReference']?>'">Delete</button></div>
```

and Viewed.php

```
$orderID = $_POST['id'] ;

if ($_POST)
{
    try {
        $sqlOrderviewed = "UPDATE `Order_Header` SET `orderViewed` = '1' WHERE `Order_Header`.`orderReference` IN ($orderID) ";
        $resultOrderupdate = $products->conn->query($sqlOrderviewed); // Execute Statement
        echo $count = $resultOrderupdate->rowCount();
    }  catch
    (PDOException $e) {  // If error in SQL
        echo "One or more errors occurred saving to database This transaction will be rolled back:" . $e->getMessage();  // Display Message on End Point
        //  $products->conn->rollback();       // Rollback SQL
    }
}
```

I am aware of the SQL Injection in this example, this is not production just trying to get an example working

Comment: What message is being shown in the console?

Comment: Nothing, I cannot get my debugger to pickup when viewed.php is called. not sure if its because its being called from within Javascript? and i get no error in my error_log, am completely stuck. its almost like my button is not even reaching the Javascript

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  What's the button on the *rendered* html - does it have a `data-id`?   What's the value of `data` in your click event?  Are there any console errors (F12 select console)?  What gets sent in the browser network tab (F12 select network)? (network tab will tell you exactly what's going, best place to debug this issue)  What gets received?  What's the value of $orderID?

Comment: $orderID is a numeric  value of the box the button appears in, this gets populated, If i simply do a href and specify the script filename it works, however i do not want to be re-directed i just need the code / php file to be executed silently

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would suggest making REST API type behaviour in your PHP that accepts JSON (as an example) which you can define with headers. So your JavaScript can stay mostly the same, just make sure you are pointing to the correct URL. But I think your PHP should look more like this:

```
    <?php 
      // Headers
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST'); //maybe make this an update to be Semantic with the SQL operation you are doing
    
      // Get raw data from the post you made in JavaScript
      $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
      $id = $data.id;

      // Use the data in your SQL
      $sqlOrderviewed = "UPDATE `Order_Header` SET `orderViewed` = '1' WHERE `Order_Header`.`orderReference` IN ($id) ";

    ?>
```

If you need more information on creating APIs with PHP I suggest these resources:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEWXbpUMODk
- https://shareurcodes.com/blog/creating%20a%20simple%20rest%20api%20in%20php
- https://github.com/bradtraversy/php_rest_myblog

I am not sure that `$(this).data("id")` is getting the data you want. I assume you want to get the value of data-id in your button? If so I would change your JavaScript to something more like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $("body").on("click","button", function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting a form ...
        let id = ev.target.getAttribute("data-id");
        let data={id: id};
        $.post("http://localhost:{port}/viewed.php",data)
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log("Message:",result);
            });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

P.S this is how I might have written the JS for this, I just find it a bit more readable (Not tested, just written in the MD editor while answering the question):

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    
    let data = {
      id: id
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/viewed.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(result){
        console.log( "result: " + result );
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am away from my laptop but I will try this later and report back. But this explains alot. Familiar with API, created various REST before this method never crossed me mind. Thanks